# "Column_name" in WHERE clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT EquipmentNumber, EquipmentType, P.AreaCode AS Location, EquipDsc FROM MajorEquipment ME
 INNER JOIN PlantAreaCodes P ON ME.PACId = P.PACId WHERE
 (@EquipNumber IS NULL OR EquipmentNumber LIKE @EquipNumber)
 AND ((SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location) IS NULL OR PACId = (SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location))
 AND (@EquipType IS NULL OR EquipmentType LIKE @EquipType)
 AND (@Comments IS NULL OR EquipDsc LIKE @Comments);
```

And I get the error "Column 'PACId' in where clause is ambiguous."

I have tried this query before, with other data and I had no issues. What's going on?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You should prealiacing your ambiguous columns, `sql` does not know, what are you want `ME.PACId` or `P.PACId`.

Comment: Although you select PACId from PlantAreaCodes, you still need to explicitly state which table you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: "Column 'column\_name' in where clause is ambiguous"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337034/mysql-column-column-name-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous)

Comment: @vp_arth I had a look at that, but I still couldn't quite understand what the issue was.

Comment: @Adherence did I not? I though `FROM MajorEquipment` clarified that?

Comment: `) IS NULL OR PACId = (SELECT` => `) IS NULL OR ME.PACId = (SELECT`

Comment: Change: `AND ((SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location) IS NULL OR PACId = (SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location))`  to: `AND ((SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location) IS NULL OR ME.PACId = (SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location))`

Comment: @vp_arth Ohhhh... right I see there. Thanks so much! If you provide that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Ty

Comment: ok, I post it below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prealiacing your ambiguous columns,
sql does not know, what are you want `ME.PACId` or `P.PACId`.

Just change
`) IS NULL OR PACId = (SELECT` => `) IS NULL OR ME.PACId = (SELECT`