# php mysqli Error: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table for category name and post. Now i need to show category name for each post like this :

```
$joinedcontent = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . CONTENT . 
" LEFT JOIN " . POST . "  ON category = id WHERE  id = ?", $row['id']);
$ccats= $joinedcontent[0]['name'];
```

In result i see this error:

`Error: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous 
Statement: SELECT * FROM cms_content LEFT JOIN cms_posts ON type = id WHERE id = ? 
Arguments:
Array
(
    [۰] => 30
)`

how do fix this error?

Comment: Try to learn using alias

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: "Column 'column\_name' in where clause is ambiguous"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337034/mysql-column-column-name-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous)

Comment: There is common id column in both table. use alias for it.

Comment: both tables have column with name id, try to use table alias and use the alias to avoid the ambiguity

Comment: Please mark the best answer, if any, as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ambiguity for the database that the "id" column specified in where clause, belongs to which table. CONTENT or POST? You have to specify the name of the table before the column name to identify it. For example:

```
$joinedcontent = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . CONTENT . 
" LEFT JOIN " . POST . "  ON category =  " . POST . ".id WHERE  " . POST . ".id = ?", $row['id']);
$ccats= $joinedcontent[0]['name'];
```

Comment: Yes, I missed one of them. The edited one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be same column available in other table. so please use table.column to avoid conflict column (ambigity)

Comment: Seems to be comment more